# Subset a data frame in R using a condition on few specific columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame in R

| id | name | class | x101 | x202 | x303 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76978 | phil | 2 | 0.407034783 | 0.001 | 0.192229687 |
| 59911 | jose | 2 | 0.327173661 | 0.004 | 0.227843273 |
| 46537 | matt | 3 | 0.590337464 | 0.005 | 0.057271545 |
| 77345 | benn | 4 | 0.293847569 | 0.002 | 0.170405643 |
| 53180 | crai | 2 | 0.844581456 | 0.003 | 0.253665748 |
| 21063 | lour | 4 | 0.080756674 | 0.002 | 0.902143356 |
| 35456 | moni | 4 | 0.445965164 | 0.004 | 0.531952568 |

I need to remove the columns that start with "x" (x101, x202 and x303) and a mean value less than 0.1. That will remove the column X202. Eventually my output should be like below:

| id | name | class | x101 | x303 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76978 | phil | 2 | 0.407034783 | 0.192229687 |
| 59911 | jose | 2 | 0.327173661 | 0.227843273 |
| 46537 | matt | 3 | 0.590337464 | 0.057271545 |
| 77345 | benn | 4 | 0.293847569 | 0.170405643 |
| 53180 | crai | 2 | 0.844581456 | 0.253665748 |
| 21063 | lour | 4 | 0.080756674 | 0.902143356 |
| 35456 | moni | 4 | 0.445965164 | 0.531952568 |

How can I do it in R?

Comment: `x[,-(which(colMeans(x[,grepl("x",colnames(x))])<0.1)+3)]` should do the trick (with `x` being your `data.frame`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you can do the following.

```
inx <- which(sapply(dat, inherits, "numeric"))
inx <- names(dat[inx])[grepl("x", names(dat[inx])) & colMeans(dat[inx]) < 0.1]
result <- dat[-which(names(dat) %in% inx)]
result 
#     id name class       x101       x303
#1 76978 phil     2 0.40703478 0.19222969
#2 59911 jose     2 0.32717366 0.22784327
#3 46537 matt     3 0.59033746 0.05727155
#4 77345 benn     4 0.29384757 0.17040564
#5 53180 crai     2 0.84458146 0.25366575
#6 21063 lour     4 0.08075667 0.90214336
#7 35456 moni     4 0.44596516 0.53195257
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
id   name  class   x101   x202   x303
76978 phil 2 0.407034783 0.001 0.192229687
59911 jose 2 0.327173661 0.004 0.227843273
46537 matt 3 0.590337464 0.005 0.057271545
77345 benn 4 0.293847569 0.002 0.170405643
53180 crai 2 0.844581456 0.003 0.253665748
21063 lour 4 0.080756674 0.002 0.902143356
35456 moni 4 0.445965164 0.004 0.531952568
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `dplyr` package to achieve this.

```
    tmp<-read.table(text="id   name  class   x101   x202   x303
76978 phil 2 0.407034783 0.001 0.192229687
59911 jose 2 0.327173661 0.004 0.227843273
46537 matt 3 0.590337464 0.005 0.057271545
77345 benn 4 0.293847569 0.002 0.170405643
53180 crai 2 0.844581456 0.003 0.253665748
21063 lour 4 0.080756674 0.002 0.902143356
35456 moni 4 0.445965164 0.004 0.531952568",header=TRUE)

select_if(tmp,function(x) ((is.numeric(x) & mean(x) > 0.1)|!is.numeric(x)))
```

Which will give you the desired output.

```
     id name class       x101       x303
1 76978 phil     2 0.40703478 0.19222969
2 59911 jose     2 0.32717366 0.22784327
3 46537 matt     3 0.59033746 0.05727155
4 77345 benn     4 0.29384757 0.17040564
5 53180 crai     2 0.84458146 0.25366575
6 21063 lour     4 0.08075667 0.90214336
7 35456 moni     4 0.44596516 0.53195257
```

Answer (score 0):

This would need adjustment depending on the data frame you have (e.g. if you had more columns), but works as is for your example:

```
cbind(df[,1:3], df[,4:6][colMeans(df[,4:6]) > 0.1])
```

However, using `grepl` you can automate to select the columns starting with "x" for **a base R one-liner**:

```
cbind(df[,!grepl("x", colnames(df))], df[,grepl("x", colnames(df))][colMeans(df[,grepl("x", colnames(df))]) > 0.1])
```

---

*The anatomy of this script:* This is telling it join the columns (`cbind`) that do not start with "x" (`df[,!grepl("x", colnames(df))]`) and those that start with "x" where the column mean is over 0.1 (`df[,grepl("x", colnames(df))][colMeans(df[,grepl("x", colnames(df))]) > 0.1]`).

Answer (score 0):

You could as well do:

```
keep <- !colnames(df) %in% names(which(sapply(df[startsWith(colnames(df), 'x')], mean) < 0.1))
(df <- df[keep])
```

Yielding

```
     id name class       x101       x303
1 76978 phil     2 0.40703478 0.19222969
2 59911 jose     2 0.32717366 0.22784327
3 46537 matt     3 0.59033746 0.05727155
4 77345 benn     4 0.29384757 0.17040564
5 53180 crai     2 0.84458146 0.25366575
6 21063 lour     4 0.08075667 0.90214336
7 35456 moni     4 0.44596516 0.53195257
```

---

This is a multi-step approach:

1. Get columns starting with `x` via `startsWith(colnames(df), 'x')`
2. Subset the dataframe on these and calculate the mean for each, using `sapply`: `sapply(df[startsWith(colnames(df), 'x')], mean)`
3. Check the mean via `which` and get the names: `names(which(sapply(df[startsWith(colnames(df), 'x')], mean) < 0.1))`
4. Lastly, these are the columns we do not want, hence `!colnames(df) %in% ...`